# Is having a keyway in aluminium for 30Nm a bad idea?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, stresses, aluminum

I'm designing an aluminium shaft hub for a 16mm keyed shaft with a maximum torque of 30Nm. However, stress analysis tells me that the keyway can suffer too much stress:

[image]

If my understanding is correct, keyways have little or no fillet, then how is stress relieved? In general, is driving an aluminium hub with a keyed shaft for ~30Nm a bad idea? There are some aluminium hubs with keyway [on the market](https://ozrobotics.com/shop/14mm-stainless-steel-key-hub-18011/), but it's not clear if they're designed for 30Nm. Could I be missing something in my design?

UPDATE: I've added 0.5 fillets in the keyway, but the stresses are still very high:

[image]

Comment: The keyway geometry is dependent on what tooling you use to form it. You could add a second keyway 90 degrees away to reduce some of the stress, or use a tapered shaft and hub to lock on since your torque is relatively low.

Comment: @jko The input to the hub is a planetary gearbox which I'm trying to keep intact. The keyway matches its output shaft. Like you said, 30Nm is rather low, but is it within expectation that so much stress will build up in the keyway? I'm just not sure if my analysis is correct.

Comment: Use a bigger key so spread the load more.

Comment: @Kar the analysis looks accurate for the model you have made, but keep in mind your model has perfectly sharp edges. These will act as stress concentrators in FEA. In reality the keyway shaping tool will have a radius/edge break, even if it's too small to see. This will reduce the stress to that of areas close to the corner, so about 17 MPa based on your analysis. You should be fine.

Comment: @jko I've added 0.5mm fillets in the keyway, but the stresses are still very high. Please see update.

Comment: @SolarMike The size I'm using is the same as that of the off-the-shelf hubs. I wonder if they suffer fatigue like my analysis suggests.

Comment: How accurate is your material model? Is it for the exact grade of Aluminium you'll be using? Is that grade truly 100% linear up until yield? Your reported results are too close to the yield point for you to take assumptions like this lightly. It looks like the model is a little over-constrained, too?

Comment: Keyways are only supposed to take a small part of the load, they are primarily for location. Although when something screwed up and the key was loaded they made interesting  spiral fatigue fractures.

Comment: @blacksmith37 If keyways take only a small part of the load, then I presume the shaft is meant to take the most part. But how does the shaft take the most part if there is clearance, albeit a small one?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Yes, the materials should be correct (1060 alloy). How come you think the model is over-constrained?

Comment: @Kar - usually these would have a tight fit and some e.g. loctite to spread the load over the shaft surface. 

Why are you designing this when they are so readily available off the shelf? Why did you choose 1060? All the commercially available ones I found are a more sensible 60XX series.

Comment: I say over constrained because I can see two faces that look to be fully fixed. Are they *really* fully fixed?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Oh. Actually the faces aren't fully fixed. Only the 8 holes are fixed.

Comment: Right - I could see two of the 8 holes, which shouldn’t be (fully) fixed...

Comment: @JonathanRSwift It's just a graphics problem. All 8 holes are shown fixed if stress isn't displayed. I agree that ideally they shouldn't be fully fixed and be bolted using SW's bolts. But because the stress buildup is in the keyway rather than the bolt holes, I thought I'd just keep it simple and have the holes fixed.

Comment: Keeping the solution simple for the the computer to solve and simple for you to set up is useless if the results that you get out are wrong.